# Setting a unique user nickname in node express app

Tags: node.js, express

I have a user profile collection in which I have the following fields:

- member_id
- userhandle
- height
- weight

I register a user with passport and generate a unique member_id for each user which is later used for getting the profile page populated and also for referrals. Following is the get profile route where user can change their details:

```
// Get User Profile Settings route 
router.get('/profilesettings/:member_id', (req, res) => {

    Profile.findOne({ member_id: req.params.member_id })
        .then(profile => {
            res.render('users/profilesettings', { profile: profile });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('could not find profile');
        });

});
```

Once this page is loaded the user can change their details and use the submit button to update their data. Following is the code for the put request:

```
router.put('/profilesettings/:member_id', (req, res) => {

    Profile.findOne({ member_id: req.params.member_id })
        .then(profile => {


            profile.userhandle = req.body.userhandle;
            profile.weight = req.body.weight;
            profile.height = req.body.height;
            profile.mobile = req.body.mobile;

            profile.save()
                .then(updatedProfile => {
                    req.flash('success_msg', 'Profile updated successfully');
                    res.redirect('/user/userdashboard');
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                });

        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('could not find record');
        });

});
```

What I want to do is ensure that the userhandle is always unique, so if the user enters a userhandle which is already taken by someone else in the profile collections there should be an error and the form should not submit. I am totaly stumped on how to put in a logic which does the following:

1- Checks if there is a difference in the userhandle submitted and the one already stored in the collection
2- Checks if the userhandle which came in the request already exists or not
3- if not then sets the userhandle to the new value and save
4- if it does it creates and error and redirects.

Would appreciate any advise. I know it's a small thing for you pros but I am learning Node and express :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you have confirmed if the member exists or not, you can do a 'count' query to check if the 'userHandle' exists or not. If the userHandle already exists you can return a 4xx status code. Otherwise, save it in the db. It would look something like this...

```
router.put('/profilesettings/:member_id', (req, res) => {

    Profile.findOne({ member_id: req.params.member_id })
          .then(profile => {

            Profile.count({userhandle: req.body.userhandle})
                .then(count => {
                    if(count != 0){
                          //return the error code
                    }
                    else{
                        //proceed with your normal flow
                        profile.userhandle = req.body.userhandle;
                        profile.weight = req.body.weight;
                        profile.height = req.body.height;
                        profile.mobile = req.body.mobile;

                        profile.save()
                            .then(updatedProfile => {
                                  req.flash('success_msg', 'Profile updated successfully');
                                  res.redirect('/user/userdashboard');
                              })
                            .catch(error => {
                                 console.log(error);
                             });
                    }

            }).catch(err => {
                 console.log(err);
            });

        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('could not find record');
        });

    });
```

Comment: Thanks Samay for your reply. I have made the changes but am getting the following error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at Profile.count.then.count (C:\Users\Amin Baig\Desktop\Projects\queesting\routes\user.js:83:86)`

Comment: The code is good...the error is coming from the image upload block. Although there is one problem. When I try to save the profile after making changes to other values then the userhandle, it does not accept it as the userhandle is the same and the if condition rejects the change.

Comment: Update the if condition to ```if(count != 0 && profile.userhandle != req.body.userhandle)```. If the answer was helpful, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Thanks Samay, that helped.